# Is it possible to have an analytic solution for this non-linear ode?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to avoid numerical computations in my code, I wonder if it is possible to find an analytical solution for the following equation,

$ \dfrac{dy}{dx}=(2Ay(x)^{-1}+2C)^{0.5} $

Here, A is a known real number and C is an integration constant which will be calculated from inital values if I can obtain a final solution.

By the way, the original equation im trying to solve is,
$ y''=-\dfrac{A}{y^2} $, I found the first equation above by using $v=dy/dx$ transformation.

Comment: The equation you need to solve falls in the class of separable variable ODE. In particular, you have $ y'=f(y)$ so the general solution is given by $ \int f^{-1}(y) dy =x+c$. In this case it seems that also the integral can be performed analitically.

Comment: @guestDiego: No, it should be $f(x)^{-1}$, not the inverse function $f^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: Thank you! I meant exactly the same thing, I had a laspus with notation!